# Zip4J - extract all items in folder straight to destination without "buffer" folder?

Tags: java, zip4j

I am extracting a zip file in Java with Zip4j.

The zip will look something like this:

```
ZipName.zip
    |
    ->foo/
        |
        ->SomeDirectory/
        ->fooBar.dll
```

I write

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("ZipName.zip");
zipFile.extractFile("foo/", "destination/");
```

And after extraction I want my destination to look like this:

```
desitnation/
    |
    ->SomeDirectory/
    ->fooBar.dll
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
destination/
    |
    ->foo/
        |
        ->SomeDirectory/
        ->fooBar.dll
```

So I want each FileHeader in `foo/` to go directly to `destination/` without creating directory `foo/` in destination. Is this possible?

Comment: Where's `/bar`?

Comment: @shmosel That was a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: I don't know zip4j, but this behavior is pretty standard for zip libraries. If there are no other files in destination, you could rename `foo` -> `destination` after unzipping. Otherwise you might be able to do it manually by listing the zip and using this to unzip one file at a time to the right place. It's likely that will be painful and fragile. A last resort. Otoh, moving files "up one directory" is cheap on all file systems I know.

Comment: @Gene Thanks for the info and I'll give up one directory a shot, sounds like it should do what I need.